# Access: Using textbox in report, how to display reference a column from a query using a different textbox

Tags: ms-access, textbox, vba, ms-access-2010

I'm trying to making a report in access that uses a bunch of dynamic textboxes. Lets say that one specific text box called A displays the current year using the control source 
    `="F" & Format(Date(),"yy")`
 and another called B displays the year before 
    `="F" & Format(Date()-360,"yy")`

I have a query called MKTCAP with columns called F15 and F14 which are updated automatically and every year, another column is added whith the next consecutive year.

Under textboxes A and B, I have textboxes C and D where i refer to this query, but here i want to use textboxes A and B to access the specific column of the MKTCAP query.

I tried `=[MKTCAP].[(A)]` and many different combinations of that, and i didnt know how to word this question on google. Am i missing something? Is there a simpler way of doing this? Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that Text1 and Text2 are your two textboxes containing F14 and F15, and Text3 and Text4 are the other ones pulling from the query:

Set the RecordSource of the form as the query MKTCAP.

Put this in the Form_Load event:

```
Private Sub Form_Load()

    Me.Text3.ControlSource = Me.Text1
    Me.Text4.ControlSource = Me.Text2

End Sub
```

and then in the After_Update event of Text1 and Text2

```
    Me.Text3.ControlSource = Me.Text1
```

and

```
    Me.Text4.ControlSource = Me.Text2
```

respectively, to keep the rowsource updated should Text1 and Text2 change whilst the form is open.

Your method of finding last year's date is slightly unusual - is this intentional? On Dec 30th, for example, both years would be the same. Why not use

```
="F" & Format(Date()-360,"yy") - 1
```

Comment: First off, thanks a lot for your reply. Just one question, I dont really understand why use a form_load event if I'm using a report and not a form. Does it matter? I'm guessing there is a Report_Load()

Comment: Ah, I misread that. Yes, report_load is what you need here. Let me know if the above does what you want it to!

Comment: Also, just to clarify, i have a bunch of textboxes that i have to refer too. Is there an easier method? And yes, my method for finding the date is intentional as all i need are the last 2 numbers of the year.

Comment: RE the dates; yep, but a year does not have 360 days (indeed it is not even a set number!). So on the 30th Dec, 2015, you would end up with Format(Jan 4th, 2015, "yy") = "15" and both boxes would read **F15**. My method will give you **F15** in one and **F14** in the other.

Comment: When you say a bunch of textboxes, do you mean more than just two years (14 and 15)? Or multiple records for each year?

Comment: Oh wow! I completely didnt catch that! Thanks for clearing that up. I guess i'll change it to what you wrote. And by a bunch of textboxes, i mean many different references to columns. So i have textboxes F13, F14, F15, F16, C13 and so on as they each refer to a column in the same query. I have about 10 different references to columns and about 20 different reports where i would need this same method to work

Comment: If the reports must automatically update when we reach 2016, then setting their ControlSource programatically is really the only option here. Since the year is not going to change whilst the form is open, we don't really need the code in the After_Update events (it is enough just to set the control source when the report loads, and not have to monitor the **F15** box to see if it changes).

Comment: This means that you just need 10 or so lines of code in the Report_Load event of each of the 20 or so reports, so it's not too bad. If your textboxes are consistently named across each report then the code could even be identical so just copy and paste! (eg. Me.txtFieldA.ControlSource = Me.txtYearCodeA, Me.txtFieldB.ControlSource = Me.txtYearCodeB, ...) etc.

Comment: I did exactly that. Thanks for all your help. Worked perfectly

Comment: No worries, glad I could help. Perhaps mark my answer as accepted if it's solved your issue?